# Get rid of unwanted text using find all from BeautifulSoup in Python

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am trying to get only the available colors of the shoes from this web: https://www.hoka.com/en/us/womens-everyday-running-shoes/gaviota-5/1134235.html?dwvar_1134235_color=BWHT&dwvar_1134235_width=Wide , but I keep getting all the colors even those that are not available.

[image]

This is the code I have:

```
li=[]
x=soup.find('div', class_ = "color-swatch-row type-swatch-image")        
for color in x.find_all("a"):      
    if color.find(class_ = 'pull-left null d-none'):
        continue
    else:
        li.append(color.get('title'))
```

Answer (score 0):

You have the anchor in your loop so you just need to check the attribute of the anchor to see if it contains the classname d-none.

```
li=[]
x=soup.find('div', class_ = "color-swatch-row type-swatch-image")        
for color in x.find_all("a"):      
    if 'd-none' in color['class']:
        continue
    else:
        li.append(color.get('title'))
```

If you are still getting all the colors try a little debugging with print statements. If you update the above to:

```
li=[]
x=soup.find('div', class_ = "color-swatch-row type-swatch-image")        
for color in x.find_all("a"):  
    print(f"Color text : {color.get('title')}, class: {color['class']}\n")
    if 'd-none' in color['class']:
        continue
    else:
        li.append(color.get('title'))
```

You should get an output similar to:

```
Color text : AIRY BLUE / SUNLIT OCEAN, class: ['pull-left', 'null']

Color text : BELLWETHER BLUE / EVENING SKY, class: ['pull-left', 'null', 'd-none']

Color text : BLACK / WHITE, class: ['pull-left', 'null']

Color text : CITRUS GLOW / SUNLIT OCEAN, class: ['pull-left', 'null', 'd-none']

Color text : HARBOR MIST / ROSE GOLD, class: ['pull-left', 'null']
```

If you don't or get an error then the html isn't parsing as expected and you should update your question with the output of what exactly is in each `color` var.

Comment: I am still getting 5 colors instead of 3

Comment: If you `print(color)` inside the loop or set a breakpoint on `color` do you get a distinct anchor each time in the loop and do any of them have the `d-none` class name?

Comment: I get all of them

Comment: When you say you get all of them do you mean that the variable color isn't a singluar element or what? When I pull the div containing these anchors locally I only get 3 colors in the `li` var with this code.

Comment: my li is this ['AIRY BLUE / SUNLIT OCEAN', 'BELLWETHER BLUE / EVENING SKY', 'BLACK / WHITE', 'CITRUS GLOW / SUNLIT OCEAN', 'HARBOR MIST / ROSE GOLD']

Comment: But what is the `color` var in the loop. We already know that `li` is all the colors, what you need to debug is why you can't weed out the one's with the none class.

Comment: For some reason I am getting ['pull-left', 'null'] in all of them. Thank you for trying to help me!

Answer (score 0):

```
li=[]
x=soup.find('div', class_ = "color-swatch-row type-swatch-image")        
for color in x.find_all("a"): 

    if color.find('span', class_="color-value swatch swatch-square swatch-image swatch-value attr--unavailable"):
        continue
    
    # print(f"Color text : {color.get('title')}, class: {color['class']}\n")
    # if 'attr--unavailable' in color['class']:
    #     continue
    else:
        li.append(color.get('title'))
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).